# Broken PHP contact form script

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to make a contactform.
And somehow it won't work.
I tried to send a email just with the mail()-function and that works.
So I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what.

When you click on the submit button, I refer to the mailer.php file.
Both file are in the same folder.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sendButton']))
{
 $to = "contact@domain.com";
 $subject = "Contactformulier Portfolio";
 $name_field = $_POST['yourName'];
 $email_field = $_POST['yourEmail'];
 $message = $_POST['yourMessage'];

 $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";

 echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
 mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
else
{
 echo "There has been some error, try again please!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: I just get the error from my else-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing all your code, my guess is that the condition for mailing is never met because there is no value set for the submit button.  Try making the condition for emailing like this:

```
if($_POST) {
  Mail Here
} else {
  error case
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your form button named "sendButton"? `<input type='submit' name='sendButton' />` If not, there's your culprit.

Comment: No. `id`s are used to identify CSS classes and as anchors (for #links) - HTML forms need `name`s.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide your HTML as well?

EDIT:

$_POST indeces are defined by the name attribute on your input elements. As you have only defined an id field on your submit input element, the condition you are checking is never met (and thus the mail is never send). Add the name attribute to your submit input element like this:

Comment: This is the complete HTML form

<form action="mailer.php" method="post" name="offerMeAJob_form" id="offerMeAJob_form">
<p class="formTitle">Your name...</p>
<input id="yourName" type="text" />
<br />
<p class="formTitle">Your email...</p>
<input id="yourEmail" type="text" />
<br />
<p class="formTitle">Your message...</p>
<textarea id="yourMessage"></textarea>
<br />
<input id="sendButton" value="" type="submit" />
</form>

Comment: $_POST indeces are defined by the name attribute on your input elements. As you have only defined an id field on your submit input element, the condition you are checking is never met (and thus the mail is never send). Add the name attribute to your submit input element like this: <input id="sendButton" name="sendButton" value="" type="submit" />